# SQL Server Equivalent to Oracle 'table of integer'

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, oracle

Is there a SQL Server equivalent to the Oracle concept of a 'table of integer'?

If so, what is the best way to represent this object in C#?

Oracle seems to provide the following:

```
OracleParameter parameter = new OracleParameter(data.parameterName, data.databaseDataType);
parameter.CollectionType = OracleCollectionType.PLSQLAssociativeArray;
```

I'm aiming to modify this code to work with a DbParameter instead of an OracleParameter and create a SQL Server stored procedure that behaves in the same way as the Oracle SP I'm working with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that what you may be looking for is a SQL Server [table-valued parameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb675163.aspx), which would map to SqlDbtype.Structured for a [SqlParameter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqldbtype.aspx). The relevant [DbType](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.dbtype.aspx) would be Object.

Comment: More info and code samples at [C# and Table Value Parameters](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/CSharpAndTableValueParams.aspx)